# Breaks from hist() into a data.frame

Tags: r, dataframe, histogram

I'm trying to put the breaks and counts from `hist` into a data.frame like this:

```
set.seed(1)

x <- rnorm(10, 3, 2)

data.frame(breaks = hist(x)$breaks, counts = hist(x)$counts)

Error in data.frame(breaks = hist(x)$breaks, counts = hist(x)$counts) : 
  arguments imply differing number of rows: 7, 6
```

But as you can see this is throwing an error because they have different lengths.C Can anyone suggest a neat way of doing this?

Alternatively, is there a way to bin a continuous variable without using `hist`?

Comment: I am sorry but could you please explain well what are trying to achieve? your syntax seems very unorthodox for R.

Comment: When you make `N` cuts in one-dimension, you will have `N-1` regions between the cuts. `class(data.frame)` doesn't allow you to have columns of uneven lengths. If you are simply try to segment your data into bins, then you are better off using `cut()`.

Comment: @Vlo I thought about `cut `. But how would I decide where the breaks should be without referring to `hist`? Or in other words, what algorithm does `hist` use to bin a variable?

Comment: @luciano `hist` seems to default to `breaks = "Sturges"`, which may possibly be related to `nclass.Sturges()` There are a lot of references to Sturges' formula/rule on Google.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The breaks are always one longer than the counts. Because the counts fall between each pair of breaks. Maybe you want to track the midpoints of the regions instead?

```
with(hist(x), data.frame(breaks = mids, counts = counts))
```

otherwise you could just assign the count for the value at the right edge of the region

```
with(hist(x), data.frame(breaks = breaks[-1], counts = counts))
```

Or you can track start/end

```
with(hist(x), data.frame(embed(breaks,2), counts = counts))
```